# rails activerecord relation join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have a country model and a travel note model. A country has many travel notes and a travel note belongs to one country.

```
class TravelNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }

  belongs_to  :country
  has_many    :chapters

  before_destroy { draft? }

  validate :validates_uniqueness_of_draft, on: :create

  enum status: { draft: 0, published: 1, archived: 2 }
  enum advice_against: { no: 0, general: 1, tourists: 2 }

  scope :country, ->(country_id) { where(country_id: country_id) }

  # further methods omitted...
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order(:iso_code) }

  has_many :travel_notes

end
```

in app/controllers/countries_controller.rb:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @countries = Country.includes(:travel_notes)
  end
  # rest of the class omitted...
end
```

in app/views/countries/index.html.haml:

```
@countries.each do |country|
        %tr
          %td= link_to country.name_de, country_travel_notes_path(country)
          %td= TravelNote.published.country(country.id).first.try :published_at
```

because of performance reason i want to remove TravelNote.published.country(country.id).first.try :published_at so that there is not hundreds of database queries anymore instead just an array of an equivalent sql query:

```
select * from countries 
left join travel_notes
on countries.id=travel_notes.country_id
```

how can i achieve it?

Comment: I am not sure, but can u try `TravelNote.published.joins(:country).where(:countries => { :id => country.id }).map(&:published_at)` if it helps

Comment: thanks Sontya, it was indeed helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to eager-load the "travel_notes" associated to the country:

```
Country.includes(:travel_notes).where(travel_notes: { status: 1} )
```

so your code will be:

> ```
> class CountriesController < ApplicationController
>   def index
>     @countries = Country.includes(:travel_notes).where(travel_notes: { status: 1} )
>   end
>   # rest of the class omitted...
> end
> ```

```
@countries.each do |country|
        %tr
          %td= link_to country.name_de, country_travel_notes_path(country)
          %td= country.travel_notes.first.published_at
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom scope to include only the published notes.

something like

```
scope :include_published, -> { proc do |_|
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT b.*
        FROM   travel_notes b
        WHERE published = 1
        GROUP BY b.country_id
      ) notes_select ON notes_select.country_id = countries.id"
     ).select("countries.*").select("#{insert what attributes you want to include }")
  end.call(self, counted_model) }
```

You have to include the attributes you want from the note in the second select clause then they will be included in the country active record result as methods with the same name.

The SQL-query can be written prettier, I just threw something together...

I use a similar technique in my project but in order to include counts of associated objects.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you don't need that `proc` in there.

Comment: Probably correct about the proc, comment. We have a proc because have it extracted to a module that generates the query depending on what models are involved.

Comment: thanks a lot Albin Svensson. That's great and in a different context i will definitely use your approach but in this case, the code of mohameddiaa27 looks simpler.